# Using regular expressions for syntax highlight

Tags: objective-c, regex, macos, nsregularexpression

I have a piece of code that assigns attributes to an `NSAttributedString` depending on whether certain keywords are present in the string or not. In other words, syntax highlight.

To find if a certain string has those keywords I am currently using regular expressions to find the location of those words with `"\\bKEYWORD\\b"`. The problem is, obviously, performance.

I first tried with `NSRegularExpression` but performance was so slow that scrolling my textview was nearly impossible. I then tried Oniguruma and things improved but it's still noticeably slow. I may try PCRE but I don't think I'll be adding much.

So, my question is: how can I speed up regular expression searches? Maybe caching the compiled expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're searching for each word individually. I would create an array of search words, then join them together with a regex alternation `|` symbol

Given search words like: `alpha, bravo, charlie, delta, echo`

Resulting complied regex: `\b(?:alpha|bravo|charlie|delta|echo)\b`

[image]

The non capture group construct `(?:`...`)` is a bit faster then the capture syntax `(`...`)`

Comment: Doing this and caching the pattern resulted in a significant increase in performance.

Comment: Could I ask how you generated the image in your answer?